# Finding duplicates in JSON file after parsing with Boost

Tags: c++, json, boost

How can I find duplicates in a JSON file after parsing it out like the code below? I want to count the number of duplicates in the data where a duplicate would have the first name, last name, and email address all match.

The JSON file is rather huge, so I won't copy and paste it here. But here is a snippet of it:

```
[  
  {  
    "firstName":"Cletus",
    "lastName":"Defosses",
    "emailAddress":"ea4ad81f-4111-4d8d-8738-ecf857bba992.Defosses@somedomain.org"
  },
  {  
    "firstName":"Sherron",
    "lastName":"Siverd",
    "emailAddress":"51c985c5-381d-4d0e-b5ee-83005f39ce17.Siverd@somedomain.org"
  },
  {  
    "firstName":"Garry",
    "lastName":"Eirls",
    "emailAddress":"cc43c2da-d12c-467f-9318-beb3379f6509.Eirls@somedomain.org"
  }]
```

This is the main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Customer.h"
#include "boost\property_tree\ptree.hpp"
#include "boost\property_tree\json_parser.hpp"
#include "boost\foreach.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numOfCustomers;

    // parse the JSON file
    boost::property_tree::ptree file;
    boost::property_tree::read_json("customers.json", file);

    cout << "Reading file..." << endl;

    numOfCustomers = file.size();

    // iterate over each top level entry
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type const& rowPair, file.get_child(""))
    {
        // rowPair.first == ""  and rowPair.second is the subtree with names and emails

        // iterate over rows and columns
        BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type const& itemPair, rowPair.second)
        {
            // e.g. itemPair.first == "firstName: " or "lastName: "
            cout << itemPair.first << ": ";
            // e.g. itemPair.second is the actual names and emails
            cout << itemPair.second.get_value<std::string>() << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The Customer class is just a generic class.

```
class Customer
{
private:
    std::string m_firstNme;
    std::string m_lastName;
    std::string m_emailAddress;

public:
    std::string getFirstName();
    void setFirstName(std::string firstName);

    std::string getLastName();
    void setLastName(std::string lastName);

    std::string getEmailAddress();
    void setEmailAddress(std::string emailAddress);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd typically insert the customer objects/keys into a `std::set` or `std::map` and define a *total ordering* that spots the duplicates on insertion.

Defining the key function and comparator object:

```
boost::tuple<string const&, string const&, string const&> key_of(Customer const& c) {
    return boost::tie(c.getFirstName(), c.getLastName(), c.getEmailAddress());
}

struct by_key {
    bool operator()(Customer const& a, Customer const& b) const {
        return key_of(a) < key_of(b);
    }
};
```

Now you can simply insert the objects in a `set<Customer, by_key>`:

```
set<Customer, by_key> unique;

// iterate over each top level array
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type const& rowPair, file.get_child(""))
{
    Customer current;
    current.setFirstName    ( rowPair.second.get ( "firstName", "?"    )  ) ;
    current.setLastName     ( rowPair.second.get ( "lastName", "?"     )  ) ;
    current.setEmailAddress ( rowPair.second.get ( "emailAddress", "?" )  ) ;

    if (unique.insert(current).second)
        cout << current << "\n";
    else
        cout << "(duplicate skipped)\n";
}
```

### Full Demo

I've duplicated 1 entry in your sample JSON, and you can see it live

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98affdc683431a26)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

#include "Customer.h"
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>

using namespace std;

namespace {

    boost::tuple<string const&, string const&, string const&> key_of(Customer const& c) {
        return boost::tie(c.getFirstName(), c.getLastName(), c.getEmailAddress());
    }

    struct by_key {
        bool operator()(Customer const& a, Customer const& b) const {
            return key_of(a) < key_of(b);
        }
    };

    inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Customer const& c) {
        return os << "{ '"
             << c.getFirstName()    << "', '"
             << c.getLastName()     << "', '"
             << c.getEmailAddress() << " }";
    }
}

int main()
{
    // parse the JSON file
    boost::property_tree::ptree file;
    boost::property_tree::read_json("customers.json", file);

    cout << "Reading file..." << endl;

    set<Customer, by_key> unique;

    // iterate over each top level array
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type const& rowPair, file.get_child(""))
    {
        Customer current;
        current.setFirstName    ( rowPair.second.get ( "firstName", "?"    )  ) ;
        current.setLastName     ( rowPair.second.get ( "lastName", "?"     )  ) ;
        current.setEmailAddress ( rowPair.second.get ( "emailAddress", "?" )  ) ;

        if (unique.insert(current).second)
            cout << current << "\n";
        else
            cout << "(duplicate skipped)\n";
    }

    cout << "\n" << (file.size() - unique.size()) << " duplicates were found\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Reading file...
{ 'Sherron', 'Siverd', '51c985c5-381d-4d0e-b5ee-83005f39ce17.Siverd@somedomain.org }
{ 'Cletus', 'Defosses', 'ea4ad81f-4111-4d8d-8738-ecf857bba992.Defosses@somedomain.org }
(duplicate skipped)
{ 'Garry', 'Eirls', 'cc43c2da-d12c-467f-9318-beb3379f6509.Eirls@somedomain.org }

1 duplicates were found
```

> **NOTE** I've adjusted the *getters* to be less wasteful by returning `const&`:
>
> ```
> std::string const& getFirstName() const        { return m_firstName;            } 
> std::string const& getLastName() const         { return m_lastName;             } 
> std::string const& getEmailAddress() const     { return m_emailAddress;         }
> ```

### BONUS

Here's the equivalent program **in 26 lines of c++14 code**:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e12402f86f877b8)</kbd>**

Comment: Added the equivalent program *in 26 lines of c++14 code*: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e12402f86f877b8)** as a bonus

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: May I ask, on these lines, what is the question mark's function? Does it work like an * in searching?

current.setFirstName( rowPair.second.get ( "firstName", "?"    )  ) ;

Comment: It's the default value. It's not question marks, really. Just string literals. The content doesn't matter (you can use `"unknown"` just as well, or `"Smith"` etc.)

Comment: Thanks! Now to decode your code and make sense of it more :) The boost documentation is a bit tough to read haha.

Comment: There's not a lot boostey going on. In fact the c++14 version uses `std::tuple`, indeed. I use tuple comparison to get the comparison without horrific manual conditions, but you could write it with three nested conditional comparisons.

Comment: Haha I see. Can you tell I'm still a wee sophomore in CS ;) all these standard libraries make life so much easier!